# Problem using GetListItemsAsync() from SilverLight targetting SharePoint 2007

Tags: silverlight

I'm developing a web part which is needed in WSS 3.0 showing some SilverLight graphics based on the view and its filtering. The view is chosen from the a web editor part and the needed web part properties are passed into SilverLight as params.

Inside the SilverLight App.xaml.cs I'm making a param array with all the web part properties.

App.strArgumentArray[1] holds the listname,
App.strArgumentArray[8] holds the viewname,
App.strArgumentArray[17] holds the webID and
App.strArgumentArray[16] holds the views SchemaXml:

```
    //From inside the web part. The strListViewQueryXML is passed as a param to SL
    SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[SomeListName];
    SPView oListView = oList.Views[SomeListNameView];
    string strListViewQueryXML = oList.Views[oListView.Title].SchemaXml;
```

Inside the MainPage.xaml.cs the SchemaXml is split up in XElements to be used in the GetListItemsAsync method.

```
            string query = App.strArgumentArray[16]; //Holds the SchemaXml

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(query))
            {
                using (XmlReader xtr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
                {
                    queryX = XElement.Load(xtr); 
                }
            }

            queryElement = queryX.Descendants("Query").First();
            viewElement = queryX.Descendants("ViewFields").First();
            optionElement = XElement.Parse(@"<QueryOptions/>"); //Empty QueryOption

            ListsSoapClient objLSC = new ListWebServices.ListsSoapClient("ListsSoap", App.serviceUri);
            objLSC.GetListItemsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetListItemsCompletedEventArgs>(objLSC_GetListItemsCompleted);                                                                    
            objLSC.GetListItemsAsync(App.strArgumentArray[1], App.strArgumentArray[8], queryElement, viewElement, null, optionElement, App.strArgumentArray[17]);
```

I feel like I've tried everything. The GetListItemAsync method works fine if I use it with only the first argument (string listName) but when I use the rest of the arguments in GetListItemAsync

```
    GetListItemAsync(string listName, string viewName, XElement query, XElement viewFields, string rowLimit, XElement queryOptions, string webID);
```

it keeps throwing a "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound." The App.serviceUri has not changed so why this error? What am I doing wrong here?

Kind regards Michael Lau Wolfsberg

Comment: Can you try to configure SharePoint WCF service to return the real error message like explained here (http://www.benday.com/2010/08/16/how-to-permanently-banish-silverlights-not-found-error-for-wcf-service-calls/)? It may help to resolve your real problem.

Comment: I've used the tool Microsoft Service Configuration Editor from the Microsoft Windows SDK to modify the includeExceptionDetailInFaults property of <serviceDebug> in the List.asmx service that I've added to my project. Still gives me same error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814627/silverlight-webservice-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-notfound) there's an advice to use a http traffic inspection tool like Fiddler to view the real message. Can you try it?

Comment: @Wolfsberg - How did you end up finding the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the error. GetListItemAsync takes both string viewName and XElement query as arguments:

```
     GetListItemAsync(string listName, string viewName, XElement query, XElement viewFields, string rowLimit, XElement queryOptions, string webID);
```

If you intent to use a specific query then don't also specify the viewName. The view name has to be set to null like this :)

```
    objLSC.GetListItemsAsync(App.strArgumentArray[1], null, queryElement, viewElement, null, optionElement, App.strArgumentArray[17]);
```

I will still try use the http traffic inspection tool since this would help me in future debugging situations :) Thanks alot for your answers Alex.